# use .js file in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, datepicker

Sorry for such a basic question but i am not that used to JavaScript.

I have a JavaScript (DatePicker.js). I want to add a TextBox on emp_master.aspx that would call the .js function.

But how do I use .js in C# i.e. where do I cal the .js file?

Comment: what you have provided is HTML not C#, you need to include the .js in your HTML with the <script> tag

Comment: I don't even know where to start :P

Comment: @Rumplin yes. that was the code used for calling it in an HTML page. I want to know how that can be done in C#

Comment: I have no clue what you want to do with it in C#, when clearly you are outputing HTML. I guess you need some more learning about what you are doing, get you facts straight first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to include js and css files on master pages (files with .master extension).

Simplest example

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Тег LINK</title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="DatePicker.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <p>...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to include in .aspx pages instead of .master

Answer (score 0):

google will give you with more answers https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=calling%20.js%20from%20.aspx&oq=calling%20js%20from%20as&gs_l=hp.11.3.0i10i30j0i30l3.13487.24791.1.27452.26.17.4.5.7.1.221.2423.0j16j1.17.0...0.0...1c.NodExE7iB2M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e714c12403361d92&biw=1024&bih=598&pf=p&pdl=300